# vagrant under cmder on Windows 10 does nothing; works under cmd.exe

Tags: windows-10, vagrant, cmder

I have a fresh Windows 10 64-bit install, which I'm attempting to set up for development.

I have

- downloaded and installed cmder, then rebooted
- downloaded and installed Vagrant, then rebooted
- downloaded and installed VirtualBox, then rebooted
- set `VAGRANT_HOME=c:\vagrant`
- used `VBoxManage setproperty machinefolder c:\virtualbox-machines`
- acquired my department's VagrantFile, and modified it to suit my filesystem.

In cmder, if I now run

```
vagrant box add http://opscode-vm-bento.s3.amazonaws.com/vagrant/virtualbox/opscode_centos-7.0_chef-provisionerless.box --name chef/centos-7.0
```

I get *no* output. No failure codes, no windows errors, no logs from vagrant. The same is true of *all* vagrant commands, up to and including `vagrant --version` and `vagrant --help`. Other commands work fine in cmder.

However, if I run a basic command line, `cmd.exe`, then the `vagrant box add` command completes correctly. An, as far as I know, identical setup worked under Windows 7 32-bit.

Can anyone suggest what might be going wrong?

Comment: 1. ConEmu version. 2. Screenshots after executing vagrant commands.

Comment: @Maximus - ConEmu looks like `ConEmu 161022 [32]` (which is a little odd, because it's a Windows 10 64-bit install - but that's what came with cmder). There's no point getting screenshots - there is _literally_ nothing after running a vagrant command. Just one blank line, then the next prompt.

Comment: Update ConEmu to latest alpha

Comment: @Maximus - now running 170709 [64]; no change. Still no output from (for instance) `vagrant --version`.

Comment: A coworker on windows had this problem this morning, he was using latest `stable` and `latest` version of `cmder` both facing this issue. I asked him to use `conemu` directly instead, he installed `conemu` using `chocolatey` and now his `vagrant` command works.

Comment: @GabLeRoux - if I run ConEmu64.exe directly from cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5, I still have the same symptom - no output. I don't know if cmder is hijacking the console behind the scenes, though.

Comment: @GabLeRoux - ah! But running it from its own directory _does_ appear to work.

Comment: Try to disable clink. Or http://conemu.github.io/en/FaqPlainShell.html#cmd

Comment: @Maximus How do I disable clink? Its checkbox is off in cmder's settings, but it may be active globally. Also, how do I tell cmder to use ConEmu basic? I can't work out where the `-basic` switch should go. (Incidentally, my system has been re-imaged to Windows 7 64-bit, and the problem is persisting).

Comment: The link I've posted shows the command you shall run. Exactly. From Win+R fo example.

Comment: @Maximus - If I run ConEmu _directly_ everything works fine. It's only if I run it through cmder that things fail. How do I add in the `-basic` switch to cmder's invocation of ConEmu?

Comment: Delete clink folder, edit cmder batch initialization file (remove clink calls), uncheck clink checkbox in ConEmu settings.

Comment: Actually, I see no sense in cmder, hotkeys and color theme are configurable in ConEmu itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something wrong with the git-for-windows that is vendored with cmder and vagrant. However, cmder allows you to have your own install of git-for-windows.

To fix this issue with vagrant working and cmder:

1. Install git for windows from https://git-scm.com/
2. Ensure your PATH includes the path to the git you just installed (default should be: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd)
3. Restart cmder

Cmder should then detect the custom git install and use that and there will no longer be a problem with vagrant.

Editing the cmder vender\init.bat is not a great solution because this can be replaced by cmder in a future update.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just talked with the guy who had the problem here at the office, he said the problem was related to its `$PATH` not being set correctly for `git.exe`.

Problem is with the way [`C:\Tools\cmder\vendor\init.bat`](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/blob/ba99f5b66a4ec532c1237b64590daf072b676e04/vendor/init.bat#L78) loads `git`. (I still don't know why `git` have anything to do with preventing `vagrant` from running).

1. Make sure `C:\Tools\cmder\bin;` comes first in the list
2. Remove cmder's `git-for-windows` (he also renamed it to a different path just to make sure it doesn't get used by cmder).
3. Use [official git binaries](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and add `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;` to to your `PATH`.

After doing this, he was able to run `vagrant` commands from `cmder` like before. Hope it helps. Good luck!